# Cordova/Phonegap: AJAX calls not working on iOS device

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, cordova

I'm building an app in Cordova/Phonegap for iOS.

I have a login form that works via an AJAX call by passing username + password to a PHP script on my server.

When I run this via localhost on my PC (Chrome, to be specific) it works absolutely fine. The AJAX call is passed onto the PHP, the PHP runs, and the response is returned.

When I run the same instance on my iOS device via the Phonegap testing app, none of the URLs/Forms submit. Nothing web-based works in any way. I have an image on the index.html page which is from an external source and this did not load on iOS.

I figured this would be a permissions issue, so I changed the header to the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: filesystem: ws: gap: file: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; child-src *; ">
```

I also added the following in my config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*"/>
```

The idea is that this would let all traffic through (for testing purposes only - I know this is not a good idea from a security perspective).

The image in index.html that's being pulled from a HTTP source, which wasn't being rendered earlier, is working now on my iOS device which is great because it means that the change of permissions has helped, but unfortunately the AJAX is still not working.

Here's what I have in my Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: filesystem: ws: gap: file: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; child-src *; ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/leaf.css">
    <title>App Name</title>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">


    <img style="width:25%; padding-top:2em;" src="img/logo.png" /> <!-- Local image, which works fine on all devices -->
    <img style="width:25%; padding-top:2em;" src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/Karmody/alaTest_Iphone01a.png" /> <!-- external image which didn't work earlier but works now since I changed the header permissions -->
    <form id="loginForm" onsubmit='return false;' action="http://LINK TO SERVER/login.php"  role="form" method="post" >

        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">


        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">


        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">

    </form>

    <h3><a href='http://google.com'>Link to page (Works in browser but not in mobile)</a></h3>


</body>
</html>
```

And here's my script file:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(device.uuid);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    $('#loginForm').submit(function(){
        var username = $("[name='username']").val();
        var password = $("[name='password']").val();
        var dataString = {username: username,password: password};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://LINK TO SERVER/login.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(responseBack){
                if(response == "success"){alert("Successfully authenticated.");}
                else{alert("Username/password incorrect.");}
            }
        });


    });

}
```

Any tips for me on what I should troubleshoot in order to get web calls to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by enabling jQuery Cors.

```
$.support.cors = true;
```